# Notification when tf topic is subscribed to?

Tags: ros, callback, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on camera based visual odometry node that publishes /tf transforms when fiducial tags are present within a camera image.  As the image process is somewhat computationally heavy, I would only like to process images only when there is a subscriber that cares about the transforms from my node.  The ImageTransport infrastructure provides a connectCallback mechanism for accomplishing this where client nodes subscribe to an image.  However, I don't see there is a similar connect callback mechanism for the TransformBroadcaster which I'm using to send transforms.  I presume this is because there is no way to tell when transforms a subscriber to /tf really cares about.

Is there a recommended way of accomplishing this?  I presume I could create a service that clients can use to manually enable/disable image processing, but I was hoping for something a bit more automatic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185799/notification-when-tf-topic-is-subscribed-to?/) by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about you make the odometry transform a service? This way, it would only run when the service is called.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0